# Alfresco REST API: How do I list folders in the site?

Tags: alfresco

Given this URL

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites/test-3
```

I get back:

```
{
   "url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/sites\/test-3",
   "sitePreset": "site-dashboard",
   "shortName": "test-3",
   "title": "Test 3",
   "description": "",
   "node": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/0352afea-797f-4b9e-be27-3bf37e54a2f1",
   "tagScope": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/tagscopes\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/0352afea-797f-4b9e-be27-3bf37e54a2f1",
   "siteManagers":
   [
         "admin"
   ],
   "isPublic": true,
   "visibility": "PUBLIC"
}
```

How to I use that info to get the list of folders in the site?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a different API. Look at this shell session:

```
$ curl -u admin:admin -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'shortName':{'values':['test'], 'match':'foo'}}" http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites/query

{
    "url" : "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/sites\/test",
    "sitePreset" : "wcmqs-site-dashboard",
    "shortName" : "test",
    "title" : "test",
    "description" : "",
        "node" : "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/e597e4c2-d307-46e3-ba4d-b911262e7261",
        "tagScope" : "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/tagscopes\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/e597e4c2-d307-46e3-ba4d-b911262e7261",
    "isPublic" : false,
    "visibility" : "PRIVATE",
    "siteManagers" : 
    [           
         "admin"  

   ]
}

// see the 'node' property up there
$ curl -u admin:admin http://p01:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/e597e4c2-d307-46e3-ba4d-b911262e7261/children
[..cmis response here..]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use CMIS. Depending on your exact needs though, you can use some built in webscripts to do the listings too

Within the root of a site, you have Containers, such as documentLibrary and wiki. You can get a list of the containers for a site from the *container.get* webscript. Take a look at org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/container.get.desc.xml for the details. The URL pattern for it, as shown in that file, is */slingshot/doclib/containers/{site}*

```
curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/containers/test
{
   "containers":
   [
      {
         "name": "documentLibrary",
         "description": "Document Library",
         "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/973338a0-db39-458e-a10d-396f00cb16a3",
         "type": "cm:folder"
      }
   ]
}
```

Next, when you know what container or folder within a container you want to use, the *treenode.get* webscript can let you list that, eg

```
 curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/doclib/treenode/site/test/documentLibary
 {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsTrimmed": false,
    "parent":
    {
       "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/92e4f8de-b919-4540-a27a-16c4e53a57bc",
       "userAccess":
       {
          "create": true,
          "edit": true,
          "delete": true
       }
    },
    "items":
    [
    ]
 }
```

I can also recommend you use http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index to view what webscripts are present in your system, and get information on them, it helps a lot for situations like this

Comment: I don't understand. When I call your second service the items collection is always empty. But when I look at the site, I have one document and one folder inside http://localhost:8080/share/page/site/test-3/documentlibrary.

Comment: That's the webscript that Share calls when doing things like the copy/move dialog. I'd suggest you use something like firebug to see exactly what Share calls in your case, and what it gets back, and use that to spot what's slightly different for you

Answer (score 0):

Load a site: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites/test-3

```
{
    "url": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/sites\/test-3",
    "sitePreset": "site-dashboard",
    "shortName": "test-3",
    "title": "test 3",
    "description": "",
    "node": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/0352afea-797f-4b9e-be27-3bf37e54a2f1",
    "tagScope": "\/alfresco\/service\/api\/tagscopes\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/0352afea-797f-4b9e-be27-3bf37e54a2f1",
    "siteManagers":
    [
            "admin"
    ],
    "isPublic": true,
    "visibility": "PUBLIC"
}
```

Get the site contents using the ID extracted from the node property: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/0352afea-797f-4b9e-be27-3bf37e54a2f1/children

Inside that is a node with the title "documentLibrary". Using its ID GUID, you can fetch some more children

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/b68db1eb-547d-4b2c-b5eb-ba207a275789/children

If you have custom properties, they will appear on the child items using this API call.

Using the ID of the child item, you can get its content.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/workspace:SpacesStore/i/2d53f464-bea0-46f3-aa0c-10b3302e661c/content

Answer (score 0):

Use this url to get folder list.

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace:SpacesStore/store_id/b0697dd1-ae94-4bf6-81c8-5e2fa098ddfa/children
```